# Efficient database searching for LIKE '%something%'

Tags: sql

I'm trying to search through phone numbers for any phone number containing some series of digits.

Obviously the following is going to be slow:

```
 Select * from customer where phone like '%1234%'
```

I need the wildcards, because the users were allowed to enter any data in the database, so it might have country codes, a leading 1 (as in 1-800) or a trailing extension (which was sometimes just separated by a space.

Note: I've already created 'cleaned' phone numbers by removing all non-digit characters, so I don't have to worry about dashes, spaces, and the like.

Is there any magic to get a search like this to run in reasonable time?

Comment: Which database are you using (SQL Server, mysql, Oracle...)?

Comment: I should have mentioned my on MS SQL Service 2008

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL, you're looking for the Full Text Search functionality http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

It specifically optimizes queries like the one you have listed, and is pretty darn fast once set up. You'll need your data in MySQL, and it must be in a MyISAM table (not InnoDB or other.)

I've used it in production and it works pretty well.

Comment: Full text search is definitely the way to go.

Comment: In a limited fashion... somewhat of a caveat. See the * operator here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html. Basically, you can use wildcards, but only at the end of a search term, not in front. I can see that being a barrier to the OPs search problem if the spaces are all taken out

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

You could make an index table if you like. It'll be a bit expensive, but perhaps it's worthwhile.

So you could turn a phone number: 2125551212 in to a zillion references based on unique substrings and build an inverted index from that:

```
1
2
5
12
21
25
51
55
121
125
212
255
512
551
555
1255
2125
2555
5121
5512
5551
12555
21255
25551
55121
55512
125551
212555
255512
555121
1255512
2125551
2555121
12555121
21255512
212555121
2125551212
```

So, for example:

```
create table myindex (
    key varchar(10) not null,
    datarowid integer not null references datarows(id)
);
create index i1myindex(key);
insert into myindex values('1255', datarow.id);
```

Depending on how deep you want to go.

For example, you could go only 4 deep, and then scan the results of those with the 4 numbers.

So, for example, if you have "%123456%", you can ask for keys with "1234" and then apply the full expression on the result set.

Like:

```
select d.* from datarows d, myindex i where i.datarowid = d.id and i.key = '1234' and d.phone like "%123456%";
```

The index should help you narrow down the lot quite quickly and the db will scan the remainder.

Obviously, you'll be generating some data here, but if you query a lot, you could some performance here.